# Call multiple queries as one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries to a single table in a database, the only difference being the limit. I like the output but I know there must be more practical ways of doing this. Can anyone suggest something?

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
if ($count > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){ 
}
}

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
if ($count > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
}
}
```

Comment: What do you need the 2-nd query for ?

Comment: #1) please stop using `mysql` as it's deprecated, please switch to `msqli` or `pdo`. #2) Why do you need the second query when you can access the 1st element of an array created by your first query and while statement?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass the limit as a parameter perhaps:

```
function doQuery($limit = 1) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($count > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

        }
    }
};

doQuery(1);
doQuery(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
if ($count > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
        //loop over all records...
    }
}

$count = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
if ($count > 0) {
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){ 
        //retrieve one record
    }
}
```